# generic listeners for swt radio buttons

Tags: java, swt

I'm developing a SWT app and in one particular form there are 14 pairs of Yes-No radio buttons. Each of these pairs have a text box associated with them. So if a user selects Yes, the associated textbox should be editable else uneditable. I find writing 28 listeners for the radio buttons really daunting. Since the radio buttons have nothing much to do than just rendering the textbox editable/uneditable I was hoping if there were some generic type of listeners in SWT that would be applicable to a set of radio buttons specified in an array or like that. Are there any frameworks or shall I have to write individual listeners?

***Edit***
I'm trying to fire an event only when the radio button is selected

`rdoExperience.addListener(SWT.CHECK, new RadioButtonSelection(
                txtExperience));`

but SWT.CHECK is causing the event to be fired on mouse hover over radio button too. I've tried using SWT.SELECTED too but it's not working either and I can't find other suitable SWT constants. W;hat should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good point. Sorry I don't know such thing.

However, you create one yourself: Instead of writing an anonymous listener for every button, you could write one - say `MyButtonListener` - and give it the <strike>button</strike> text box as an argument. Than you instantiate `MyButtonListener` with the appropriate text box as an argument. Than in the Listeners appropriate callback method you enable or disable the text box.

**Edit:** My bad. Of course I meant you could give it your *text box* like `radioBtn.addListener(SWT.SELECTED, new MyButtonListener(textfield1));`

Comment: "..instantiate MyButtonListener with ... " means adding untyped listeners for each of the radio buttons like `radioBtn.addListener(SWT.SELECTED, new MyButtonListener("radioBtnName"));` ?

Comment: oops, I meant something like `radioBtn.addListener(SWT.SELECTED, new MyButtonListener(textfield1));`

Comment: SWT.SELECTED didn't work for me and I used SWT.CHECK. Its working but I'm getting sth. unexpected too. The radio button fires events on mouse hover too. What's the appropriate SWT constant for that.. I couldn't find a suitable one.

Answer (score 0):

You could create one SelectionListener and add it to each of the radio buttons. Then you can ascertain which button was pressed from the selection event and map that to a text box. For the mapping you could use an array or hashtable.